# how to dynamically set size selector input for ngb pagination

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have the below code working fine

```
 <ngb-pagination class="d-flex justify-content-end" [collectionSize]="100" [pageSize]="5"
  [(page)]="currentPage" [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" (pageChange)="getToPage(currentPage)" [boundaryLinks]="true"
  [ellipses]="true" size="lg"></ngb-pagination>
```

As I read from the official documentation link - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/api, it is said the **size** input can be set to "lg" or "sm" in html.

I want it to be responsive which means for small screens **size** should take "sm" and for medium plus screens it should take "lg".
The link doesn't have the information of how to change size dynamically.
Doing with CSS is an alternative way but I want it to be done ng Bootstrap way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable for the current size `size: string = 'sm';`, put it in template `[size]="size"` and change whenever you need.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l4cfzf?file=app%2Fpagination-size.html

**Edit**
To react to window reaize you need to set up Host Listener

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    // check/set the size
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but actually i need it to set when i resize the screen

Comment: Then you need to subscribe to window events, see the edit part.